# The family of finite unions of half-open intervals forms a ring of sets

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we define $X$ to be : $\{X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is a finite union of intervals of the form $[x,y)\} = R$.

I want to show $X = [x_{1},y_{1}) \cup ... \cup [x_{n},y_{n})$ is a ring of sets.

So we need to show that union, intersection, and subtraction are in $R$. Union makes sense to me but it is the other two I am a little lost on. If we intersect two half open intervals, then I believe we get either a closed interval or the empty set which is dependent on what the half open intervals are in the first place. The same argument can be applied to subtraction. The problem is I am having a hard time showing this.

$A,B \subseteq R$ then $A \cap B = ([x_{1},y_{1}) \cup ... \cup [x_{n},y_{n})) \cap ([u_{1},v_{1}) \cup ... \cup [u_{m},v_{m})) =$ ?

Note that one interval goes to $n$ and one goes to $m$ since they could be different intervals.

Comment: Use the distributive property for $A \cap B$. See what you get.

Comment: Thats the problem. You cant assume the nth term and the mth term are going to intersect can you?

Comment: Right. Maybe they intersect and maybe they don't. If they do intersect, what is the intersection? Another half-open interval.

Comment: That makes sense to me. In terms of what I started work wise above, how would I go about finishing it that would explain that idea?

Comment: It the nth term and the mth term do not intersect then you have written the empty set in a complicated way. You can delete all these different versions of writing the empty set.